# How to share App Deep Link vs. Regular link on Facebook accounting for mobile and desktop

Tags: mobile, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-share, deeplink

I am working on a facebook sharing functionality for a site that is used on both mobile and desktop. We have a deep link we can use to link to the apps and will take the user to the app store if the app is not installed, when on mobile.

This is perfect but in the case that the share is opened on a desktop machine the experience is less than desirable.

Ideally, we would like to find a way for if they share is opened on desktop that the call to action / button goes to the website.

Worst case I would think that we put a redirect to the website when the App Deep Link is clicked on a desktop machine.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

[Branch](http://branch.io) has a free solution for this. Their links are smart enough to direct desktop users to the website and mobile users to the store if that's what you want to do. They also have an SDK for routing and attribution.